# VS2010 cannot find type ControlTemplate even though System.Windows is referenced

Tags: silverlight, xaml, reference, controltemplate, custom-controls

I'm trying to learn Silverlight here, creating a custom control template, however VS2010 refuses to recognize the [`ControlTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate%28VS.95%29.aspx) type in markup code, even though I have referenced the `System.Windows` and `System.Windows.Controls` assemblies (which is by default when basing the project on the standard Silverlight Application template). I'm trying to recreate [this seen on another SO stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199866/silverlight-imagebutton-usercontrol).

I've tried putting this code directly into a file (i.e. ImageButton.xaml) and nothing else:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonTemplate">
    <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: add refernce System.Windows.Controls

Comment: Have you referenced the right versions of the assemblies?

Comment: Can you please just put up u r code here..,, it will be helpful to point out what is going wrong..:)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to answer this question authoritatively without knowing a little more context, such as what type of file you are placing this in, and what the exact error is from Visual Studio. I imagine that you're getting an error such as:

`The type 'ControlTemplate' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`

or possibly:

`Property 'Content' does not support values of type 'ControlTemplate'`

These are caused by placing the template in the wrong place - for example, if you create a new `UserControl` (via Add -> New Item) and delete the contents of the file and paste in your code, then you will get this error, since the xaml has no references to `ControlTemplate`.

The best place to put your `ControlTemplate` is somewhere reusable, such as a new "Resource Dictionary" (again, add it via Add -> New Item -> Silverlight Resource Dictionary) and then place your code *inside* the `<ResourceDictionary ...></ResourceDictionary>` tags.

If you want to place it within a `UserControl` (the source of the second error) then you should add it to the `Resources` section of that control, for example:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonTemplate">
        <Image Source="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </ControlTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
```